# execute a method when view controller is loaded swift

Tags: swift

I need help. I have some JSON to show on the screen when the `UIViewController` screen is loaded without performing any `onClick`.

I have tried these three methods which did not work at all

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    referalDetailsFromDB()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    referalDetailsFromDB()
}

override func viewDidLoad() { 
    super.viewDidLoad() 
    referalDetailsFromDB() 
}
```

All the above functions are not loading my data automatically when a screen is launched. Please, someone, help me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: First, Check are you getting values from database? and Second, how you are displaying data to your viewController?

Comment: Add implementation of 'referalDetailsFromDB()' function.

Comment: @BhavikModi yes dear I am getting the values all is good only the method not getting executed when screen is launched

Comment: @BhargavR how to add implementation of function

Answer (score 0):

you can call your method previous viewcontroller

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UIViewControllerID") as! UIViewController
nextViewController.referalDetailsFromDB()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: I am getting error of this "Cannot use instance member 'storyBoard' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

Comment: your previous viecontroller is AppDelegate or not?

Comment: hey, yesterday it was not working today viewdidload is working